# SEO - How does crawler handle domainname itself?

Tags: web-crawler, seo, google-crawlers

I am planning to grab a domain for a new web project. I'm not a SEO-pro but I know some stuff about SEO, HIT and Page Rank algorithms and did some [research](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/domain) on domain names and their role in SEO, too.

I'm having a hard time about finding out more about the role of the domainname itself. Perhaps you can make this clear for me on a small example. Let's assume that I'd plan a web site for "best friends".

I would think about domains like this:

- www.friends-best.com
- www.for-best-friends.com
- www.best-friends.com
- www.bestfriends.com

Assuming that people would type "best friends" into their search engine, which one would be the best? I would assume "www.bestfriends.com".

My confusion: a domainname doesn't consist of different words, it's one big string and every example does contain the substring "best" and "friends". How would a Search Engine handle those domains if they would contain exactly the same websites: same titles, content, alt-Tags, sitemaps, incoming and outgoing links, metadescriptions and all the SEO stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chris, I would go for bestfriends.com as search engines are really don't care what your domain is and give search rank by considering many factors apart from domain name.

Choose name that is small and easy to remember and should contains word that can help your customer to identify your services.

Kindly refer this video from Google that explain the impact of domain name in search ranking.

www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAWFv43qubI